# Swift Generic Type in class with double protocol inheritance

Tags: swift

I've got 2 protocols:

```swift
protocol FirestoreInitializable {
```

```swift
protocol Training: FirestoreInitializable {
```

Now when creating a generic class conforming to FirestoreInitializable

```swift
class FirestoreListener<T>: ObservableObject where T: FirestoreInitializable {
```

When using it:

```swift
@Published var allTrainings: FirestoreListener<Training>
```

It generates the error:

```swift
Type 'any Training' cannot conform to 'FirestoreInitializable'
```

Now because the protocol is generic it won't work, only with specifying the specific struct, how can I use all structs conforming to Training use this class?

Comment: "Now because the protocol is generic it won't work" No, it's because protocols don't conform to protocols. The only thing you can put in those angle brackets is the name of an object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, generic parameters must be something specific, not protocols. But you can avoid using a concrete class for `allTrainings` by introducing another generic parameter to constrain it:

```swift
class Test<SomeTraining: Training> {
  @Published var allTrainings = FirestoreListener<SomeTraining>()
}
```

(Assuming you have everything declared as you described in the original question:)

```swift
import Combine

protocol FirestoreInitializable { }
protocol Training: FirestoreInitializable { }

class FirestoreListener<T: FirestoreInitializable>: ObservableObject { }
```